# @font-face breaks in IE over HTTPS?

Tags: https, internet-explorer-9, font-face

Trying to solve a problem but am running into a wall. I have a website hosted by my old university. They transitioned to serving all pages using HTTPS. For some reason this is giving IE fits.

Using the FontSquirrel generator for all fonts. Works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera on Win or Mac. In IE8 the fonts render but are replaced with stand-ins on page reload. In IE9 they won't render at all. File is rendering in IE9 mode, everything validates as HTML5.

The crazy thing is that everything works if I check it on my test server (Mac running Apache2). The U server is Apache, all fonts are hosted on the server, and have spent two days trying to figure out what gives. Can't find any other issues online with @font-face conflicting with HTTPS but that seems like it is what is happening. Any ideas? I have zero control over the host server.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer that can help you in the large, but I was able to fix this problem locally by modifying my IE9 settings as follows:

1. Tools -> Internet Options
2. Select the 'Advanced' tab and scroll down to 'Security'
3. uncheck 'Do not save encrypted pages to disk'
4. OK

I went around on this for a few days, before I found any type of joy on this. Unfortunately, I can't think of any way around this problem other than posting these instructions in secure sections of the site or not using `@font-face`.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issues as the original poster. However the 'Do not save encrypted pages to disk' flag is not checked on my system.